# Finding determinant of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am trying to find the determinant of this matrix but was told by my teacher that we wouldn't need to find the determinant of more than $3\times 3$ matrices so I am guessing there is a way of solving this without knowing how to solve a proper $4\times 4$ matrix. I think its something to do with the zeros but not sure. Would be grateful for a hint at the right direction.

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: For an upper matrix, like this one, the determinant is equal to the product of the elements on the main diagonal.

Comment: What's your definition of the determinant from your class? Do you know what happens when you do row operations?

Comment: thanks guys, i was just wondering then, does a lower triangular matrix also have a determinant that is equal to the product of the elements in the diagonal like the upper matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using the cofactor method the determinant becomes

[image]

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29